# "perform in a play at the drama festival" or "perform at the drama festival"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I would like to express a situation where a hero of a story is going to perform at a school's drama festival, and he will perform as an actor in a play. He is writing to his friend and telling him about this situation.

Can you catch the situation written above when you say

**"I will perform at the school's drama festival."**

or should you say

**"I will perform in a play at the school's drama festival."**

or something else?

Comment: Both are equally correct; it depends on how much detail he wants to go into about his acting.

Comment: Both are correct but less colloquial than "I'm going to be in a play at the school's drama festival."

Comment: @KateBunting Oh, I see! Now I understand better. Thank you very much

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Thank you very much! It really helps me.